# In postfix, how can I allow only certain users to send mail as any other user?

Tags: postfix

My mail server's default configuration uses the `reject_authenticated_sender_login_mismatch` setting of `smtpd_sender_restrictions` to prevent an arbitrary user A from sending email as user B (in the FROM field).  I realize this is generically a good policy, because even one compromised user account would basically open up my mail server as a spam relay.

However, I would like to allow **specific** users (via a whitelist) to send mail as *any* user.  For example, I would like to have my web server authenticate itself as `x@example.com` but then be able to send email on behalf of `user1@example.com`, `user2@example.com`, etc.

All other authenticated users should only be able to send email as themselves.

I think I'm on the right trail with the `/etc/postfix/sender-login-maps.cf` file, which currently contains:

```
dbpath=/home/user-data/mail/users.sqlite
query = SELECT permitted_senders
FROM (
    SELECT permitted_senders, 0 AS priority
    FROM aliases
    WHERE source='%s'
    AND permitted_senders IS NULL
    UNION
    SELECT email as permitted_senders, 2 AS priority
    FROM users
    WHERE email='%s'
    )
ORDER BY priority LIMIT 1;
```

I'm not sure how to modify this to accomplish what I want.

Comment: [smtpd_sender_login_maps`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_sender_login_maps) should help you achieve it

Comment: Thanks, I found that file but I'm not sure how to modify the SQL query it contains to accomplish what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out how to modify the query in `/etc/postfix/sender-login-maps.cf` to allow any user with "admin" privileges (as defined in the `users.sqlite` table) to send email as any other user at the same domain:

```
SELECT permitted_senders
FROM (
    SELECT permitted_senders
    FROM (
        SELECT permitted_senders, 0 AS priority
        FROM aliases
        WHERE source='%s'
        AND permitted_senders IS NULL
        UNION
        SELECT email as permitted_senders, 2 AS priority
        FROM users
        WHERE email='%s'
        )
    ORDER BY priority LIMIT 1
    )
UNION
SELECT email as permitted_senders
FROM users
WHERE privileges="admin"
AND SUBSTR(email, INSTR(email, '@') + 1) = SUBSTR('%s', INSTR('%s', '@') + 1);
```

So basically, if `x@example.com` is set as an admin (which you can do in the user database, or through your account configuration interface), then `x@example.com` will be allowed to send mail as `user1@example.com`, `user2@example.com`, etc.  This seems like a reasonable policy to me.